# Filter data from array object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having the json below:

```
 [ { status: 'complete',
    type: 'bid',
    amount: 0,
    units: 0,
    activeId: 146,
    id: 3 },
  { status: 'complete',
    type: 'ask',
    amount: 0,
    units: 0,
    activeId: 146,
    id: 1 },
  { status: 'pending',
    type: 'ask',
    amount: '1009',
    units: 0.996,
    activeId: 146,
    id: 2,
    env: 'newInsert' },
  { status: 'complete',
    type: 'ask',
    amount: 0,
    units: 0,
    id: 2,
    activeId: 146 },
  { status: 'complete',
    type: 'bid',
    amount: 0,
    units: 0,
    activeId: 146,
    id: 4 },
  { status: 'pending',
    type: 'bid',
    amount: 1012,
    units: 3.004,
    id: 11,
    activeId: 146,
    env: 'newInsert' } ]
```

**In this array I need to remove object where id is same and it change from status "pending" to "complete"**
for ex:

```
{ status: 'pending',
    type: 'ask',
    amount: '1009',
    units: 0.996,
    activeId: 146,
    id: 2,
    env: 'newInsert' },
  { status: 'complete',
    type: 'ask',
    amount: 0,
    units: 0,
    id: 2,
    activeId: 146 } 
here same id of type ask and status changed pending to complete.
```

I tried in general way to loop with foreach and match and extract the result but is there any specific way or any filter which group the things and extract.

Comment: please add the result as well. btw, what means filtering and changing status?

Comment: [ { status: 'complete',
    type: 'bid',
    amount: 0,
    units: 0,
    activeId: 146,
    id: 3 },
  { status: 'complete',
    type: 'ask',
    amount: 0,
    units: 0,
    activeId: 146,
    id: 1 },  
  { status: 'complete',
    type: 'bid',
    amount: 0,
    units: 0,
    activeId: 146,
    id: 4 },
  { status: 'pending',
    type: 'bid',
    amount: 1012,
    units: 3.004,
    id: 11,
    activeId: 146,
    env: 'newInsert' } ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using functions `filter` and `some`

```js
var array = [{    status: 'complete',    type: 'bid',    amount: 0,    units: 0,    activeId: 146,    id: 3  },  {    status: 'complete',    type: 'ask',    amount: 0,    units: 0,    activeId: 146,    id: 1  },  {    status: 'pending',    type: 'ask',    amount: '1009',    units: 0.996,    activeId: 146,    id: 2,    env: 'newInsert'  },  {    status: 'complete',    type: 'ask',    amount: 0,    units: 0,    id: 2,    activeId: 146  },  {    status: 'complete',    type: 'bid',    amount: 0,    units: 0,    activeId: 146,    id: 4  },  {    status: 'pending',    type: 'bid',    amount: 1012,    units: 3.004,    id: 11,    activeId: 146,    env: 'newInsert'  }];

var result = array.filter(o => {
  var transition = o.status === 'pending' ? 'complete' : 'pending';  
  return !(array.some((io) => io.id == o.id && io.status === transition));
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the items that have the same id you can create an object by id, and then check the lengths (using reduce):

```js
var arr = [{    status: 'complete',    type: 'bid',    amount: 0,    units: 0,    activeId: 146,    id: 3  },  {    status: 'complete',    type: 'ask',    amount: 0,    units: 0,    activeId: 146,    id: 1  },  {    status: 'pending',    type: 'ask',    amount: '1009',    units: 0.996,    activeId: 146,    id: 2,    env: 'newInsert'  },  {    status: 'complete',    type: 'ask',    amount: 0,    units: 0,    id: 2,    activeId: 146  },  {    status: 'complete',    type: 'bid',    amount: 0,    units: 0,    activeId: 146,    id: 4  },  {    status: 'pending',    type: 'bid',    amount: 1012,    units: 3.004,    id: 11,    activeId: 146,    env: 'newInsert'  }];


var map = arr.reduce((ac, x) => ({
  ...ac,
  [x.id]: [...(ac[x.id] || []), x]
}), {})


var res = Object.keys(map).reduce((ac, x) =>
  map[x].length > 1 &&
  map[x].some(z => z.status == 'pending') &&
  map[x].some(z => z.status == 'complete') ?
  ac : [...ac, ...map[x]], [])

console.log(res)
```

Comment: **The OP wants to remove those elements with:** same id and the transition from status pending to status complete.